# How to change windows time server on windows server 2012?

Tags: group-policy, windows-server-2012, powershell

In windows computer, system is using "time.windows.com" to sync the time. I need o modify the time server for windows user on its logon and want to enforce using group policy.

Case: we have windows server 2012, with 10 users on that domain. The system should update time of each user computer when user logon to system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

best practice is secure ntp on domain .
For client of the domain ad give the ntp source to ad client .

To setup on the server the source use that command (for 2008+ server):
w32tm /config /manualpeerlist:0.fr.pool.ntp.org

change manualpeerlist for your timezone (check ntp project : http://www.pool.ntp.org/en/use.html )

Answer (score 4):

If you are running an Active Directory domain, the member computers will synchronize with the domain controllers. The domain controllers will synchronize with whichever Domain Controller holds the PDC emulator role.

Thus there is no need to configure each machine. They are going to synchronize automatically using NTP.

Comment: Yes, they will sync automatically, but I want to enforce them to sync from "uk.pool.ntp.org" when user logon.

Comment: Then you should set the Domain controller that is the PDC emulator to sync with that time server. Nothing good will come from configuring the Domain members to go out and sync on their own... you are not following best practices at that point and there is a chance that it will cause problems.

Answer (score 1):

the time hierarchy in a windows forest so that all members sync time from the domain controllers.  You should not set the members to sync time on their own as it could affect their ability to log on to the domain.